# Use calculus to show increase

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, derivatives

Let $n> 1$ be an integer and let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$  be positive real numbers, all between $0$ and $1$. Is it possible to prove that
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-x_i)}\
$$
will increase as $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ increases?  ($n$ must stay the same)

This is a part of the proof on probability theory. Numerator is the sum of probabilities and denominator is the probabilities of at least one event, and $x_i$ and $y_i$ are probability units of events.

I thought about using **derivative** to show that decreasing any $x_i$ will decrease the whole thing, but wasn't sure how to apply derivative on product/sum.

Answer (score 0):

Is calculus a necessity (I know it is in the title,  but in the body that just seems to be your method) ?

If not you have that, with $f(n)$ being the expression you give, $$f(n+1)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}+x_{n+1}}{1-(1-x_{n+1})\prod_{i=1}^{n}{(1-x_i)}} $$

It's easy to see that $f(n+1)>f(n)$ as the denominator has decreased $(1-x_{n+1}<1)$ while the numerator has increased, so this function is increasing.

Comment: Is it really true that the denominator increases?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger denominator will obviously decrease

Comment: Your answer increased n to n+1, which is not what I meant. I want to keep n and only increasing x_i (x_1 ... x_n) which is why I think calculus is a good choice.

Comment: Well: $$\lim_{x_i\to 1^- \forall i}{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}}=n$$ while $$\lim_{x_i\to 1^- \forall i}{1-\prod_{i=1}^n {1-x_i}}=1-[(1-x_1)(1-x_2)... (1-x_n)]=1$$. So $f(n)\to n $ and is therefore increasing.

Comment: @RhysHughes Can you change your answer with your new comment?

Comment: @RhysHughes So the limit of this function is n. Why would this show the function is increasing?

Comment: Because $n$ is large, especially larger than $1$, and the larger values of $x_i$ cause the function to approach $n$

Comment: What does 1−∀i mean here? @RhysHughes

Comment: $x_i\to 1^-$ means that $x_i$ approaches $1$ from the left hand side (i.e. as it increases from $0.99...$). $\forall i$ means this happens in every case of $i$.

Comment: @RhysHughes Ok, good. Can you update your original answer?